# How to match any character in regex

Tags: regex

How can I match all characters including new line with a regex. 
I am trying to match all characters between brackets "()". I don't want to activate Dot matches all.

I tried

```
\([.\n\r]*\)
```

But it doesn't work.

```
(.*\) This doesn't work if there is an new line between the brackets.
```

I have been using http://regexpal.com/ to test my regular expressions. Tell me if you know something better.

Comment: Why not add the dot matches all modifier? It's why it exist.

Comment: Because I also need the dot to not match the new line. The regex is longer, but only this part is not working.

Comment: Still confused. If you intend to match all characters, including the new line, then it makes not difference if `.` *also* matches new lines.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, He has a larger regex which is already written in which the `.` means `[^\n\r]`, and he wants it to mean that. He doesn't want to have to go through the whole expression changing all `.`'s to `[^\n\r]` when he could just change this one bit of the expression instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd usually use something like `\([\S\s]*\)` in this situation.

The `[\S\s]` will match any whitespace or non-whitespace character.

Comment: As a side, what's the difference between `/.*/s` and `[\s\S]*`

Comment: @Jason: From a practical point-of-view: no difference that I'm aware of. From a regex engine implementation point-of-view: I have no idea! From this answer's perspective: the OP hasn't specified what language/platform they're using; the `[\S\s]` syntax should work on any flavour of regex; the syntax for specifying dot-matches-anything varies across different flavours (assuming that they even support it in the first place).

Comment: Thanks. I understand now why the OP does not wish to add the modifier. Nonetheless, I wanted to ensure I wasn't going nuts - as there should not be a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The first example doesn't work because inside a character class the dot is treated literally (Matches the . character instead of all characters).

```
\((.|[\n\r])*\)
```